# Reason why "onSaveInstanceState" is not called when "back button" is pressed?

Tags: android

Is there a particular reason why "onSaveInstanceState" is not called when the "back button" is pressed? It makes sense to me that view state SHOULD be saved when I press the back button. Is there a particular use-case that the Android developers had in mind that means actually its better that view state is NOT saved when one presses back?

Answer (score 2):

When performing the back action the activity and fragments will be destroyed. Why should the instance be saved when you don't want to create the activity again (e.g. orientation change).

If you want to saved some data, or better, pass it back to the calling activity/fragment, then you should use the onActivityResult mechanism. For that you have to start the activity with the "start for result" method and set the result in an intent when back button has been pressed.

Comment: And if you want to persistently store data on navigating away, you should use onResume() or onPause().

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are 3 levels of data persistence: savedInstanceState, SharedPreferences, and SQL data. If any, I think the data I want to save fits best into SharedPreferences, because that is essentially what it is: preferences. But then, why not put all viewState in SharedPreferences? What is the use of savedInstanceState at all?